# How to wrap text around landscape page

Tags: landscape, wrap

I have from time to time a landscape page. I would like that text around it just normally flows. So something how figure environment works. So that it is not really important where you exactly define the figure, LaTeX moves it around so that text nicely flows. With landscape it does not do that.

Comment: Currently I am using `pdflscape` with `landscape` environment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends a little on the kind of landscape page you want to create. The easiest way to do it is to put your landscape material into a caption-less `[p]` float (except it is a figure or table which should have a caption). Without the caption the float number isn't increased so it doesn't affect other, "real" floats.

You can create the landscape mode then by yourself by rotating the content. If this is a image use `\includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textheight]{file}`. For text you can use the following code or something similar. With this method the header and footer of the landscape page will not be different then on other pages. This might be want you want or not.

(The `lipsum` package and macros are just for adding a dummy text to show the result and are not required in the final document.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{figure}[p]
   \rotatebox{90}{%
     \begin{minipage}{\textheight}%
         % your text
         \lipsum[1-5]
     \end{minipage}%
  }%
  % No caption, then the figure number is not changed
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If the `minipage` contains any special things like verbatim material you need to use either `\Rotatebox` from the `realboxes` package or the `adjustbox` macro or environment from the `adjustbox` package to do the rotation (and even the `minipage`:
`\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textheight,angle=90} ... \end{adjustbox}`)

---

Or you can use the `afterpage` package and macro to place the landscape content onto the next page. This doesn't allow for verbatim content but for the use of `pdflscape` which rotates the pages also inside the PDF viewer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\afterpage{%
  \clearpage% To flush out all floats, might not be what you want
  \begin{landscape}
  \lipsum[1-5]
  % must not include verbatim content
  \end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the `afterpage` solution work if there are other non-landscape floats defined on the same page?  When I try it (with or without `clearpage`), the other non-landscape floats on the same page, even those that are defined *after* the landscape float, appear *before* it in the output.

Comment: @MikeShulman: Using `\afterpage` the `landscape` is not a real float and the `\clearpage` or may some command inside `\begin{landscape}` is flushing all floats. You might try the `flafter` package which forces floats to only appear after where they are defined in the text, never before.

Comment: +1 fantastic answer. `\afterpage` was just what I needed.

Comment: ``afterpage`` doesn't seem to work with the ``chapterfolder`` package. It complains about a missing file if an ``\input`` is wrapped inside the ``\afterpage`` macro.