# Incompatibility between classicthesis and afterpage

Tags: floats, errors, classicthesis

It looks like there is an incompatibility between `afterpage` and `classicthesis` :(
I successfully run this example: [How to wrap text around landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-wrap-text-around-landscape-page).

But as soon as I incorporate it in my classic thesis document it does not work anymore (float error)… Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I could run this example with `classicthesis` without error. Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Thanks for your tips!

Trying to reproduce and fix the bug a few days later, it's gone…
I guess the issue was linked to some other details in my doc that have been changed by now. If I ever manage to reproduce it, I'll post back here and report what's going on.

This is weird as before posting, I tried to clean all aux files and then to restart my computer, and still the problem was there… Sorry for this junk question.

Comment: Please only post solution in the answer sections. You can edit your original question to provide more information or add comments like these below it. I converted your post now to a comment to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Because you indicated that the issue seems not reproducible I like to close the question for now otherwise it will be in the section for unanswered questions forever. If you can reproduce it simply mark it for moderator attention or reply to this comment by adding a comment which includes '@MartinScharrer', and ask for it to be reopened.