# How to place a table on a new page with landscape orientation without clearing the current page?

Tags: floats, positioning, landscape

I'd like to place a table on a new page with landscape orientation. To do so, I use

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

However, this clears the current page, places the table on the next page with landscape orientation, and restarts typesetting in a new page with portrait orientation.

**Question** I'd like to place the table on a new page (as it is currently done) but to avoid to clear the current page. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `center` inside `table` but `\centering` instead. DO NOT USE FORMATTING environments AROUND floating environments like `table` or `figure`. EVERYTHING for it must be placed inside the floating environment.

Comment: Related question: [How to wrap text around landscape page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11471/2975).

Comment: @Macro: I adapted my linked answer to this specific case. The my answer below. (Also note that you need to write `@username` not `#username`, but this might just be a typo.)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Similar like my answer to [How to wrap text around landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-wrap-text-around-landscape-page/11473#11473) I would use `\afterpage` from the `afterpage` package to place the table at the next page of where it was declared. Here a non-floating replacement of `table` is used instead, e.g. the `\captionof{table}{...}` is used (`capt-of` or `caption`) package.

One issue are potential other `table`s which should be flushed beforehand. Otherwise the non-floating `table` replacement might appear earlier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            A & B & C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MartinScharrer, what do you mean by "flushing potential tables beforehand"? I guess, in my case your solution doesn't work exactly because of that, but I am not expert enough to be sure about...

Comment: @Py-ser: I mean to flush the float buffer, e.g. place all processed but not yet placed tables or figures. You can force that using `\clearpage`. However, this creates a page break, so `\afterpage{\clearpage}` would be better. This forces the placement of any yet unplaced floats after the next normal page break. Not that this will lead to top placement (like the `[t]` optional argument of `{table}` would do) or a full float page (like `[p]`) if there are more or larger floats to be placed. As you can see, my code above uses `\clearpage` as the first command in `\afterpage` to do exactly that.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, thanks! Does this still hold in a `two-columns` case? I can't manage to avoid blank breaking before the `landscape` page.

Comment: @Py-ser: This makes in more difficult. Not sure but I think the `landscape` page adds a page break of it's own.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, thank you. I will make a new question then.

Comment: I posted a follow up question using this MWE because this MWE is exactly doing what I need, however I need a *ROTATED* pagenumber as well. See my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258595/74646

Comment: I'm trying this technique, well all of them! The problem is that my table has a huge left margin on the landscaped page, and no right margin. How do i fix this and make it centered on the landscaped page from left to right? Note: It works fine if I have a left-to-right narrow table, but not with a long one (the whole point of landscaping it!).

Comment: So using this: 
 `\newgeometry{left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm,top=0.1cm}` 
just before `\begin{landscape}`
and `\restoregeometry` just after `\end{landscape}` worked!

Comment: @travelingbones your solution for margins caused the page number on the following page to disappear for me...

Comment: @LShaver In IEEEtrans format that worked for me, in lncs fomat i'm having similar + other problems...haven't found a workaround (haven't really looked yet)

Comment: @LShaver this worked: 
\usepackage[pass]{geometry} 
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,top=3cm} %% set the margins
\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\centering
\begin{table}
...
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry %% put margins back to default

Comment: @travelingbones that worked, with two caveats: the `[pass]` option threw an error, and wasn't necessary. Also, left/right and top/bottom follow the rest of the document, not the landscape orientation.

Comment: @MartinScharrer thank you for the code. I'm having issues using commands like \toprule inside tabular with this set up: "The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed." Any idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: @a_bet: AFAIK `\toprule` is defined by the `booktabs` package. Please check if it was loaded.

Answer (score 32):

You could use the sidewaystable environment from the [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
text text text text
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{4cm}% to simulate a table
  \caption{A rotated table}
  \label{tab:test}
\end{sidewaystable}
text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried it but it produces the same result as with pdflscape. However, afterpage makes it work, as suggested in the link provided by Martin Scharrer. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Marco: `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` let the text flow. I'd be really interested in seeing an example in which the text doesn't flow. Could you please provide such a minimal example?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, how can I let the table take one whole page and centered in that page, within the `sidewaystable` context?

Comment: It looks likt this: https://imgur.com/a/eOiAg

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It works, but the page has been placed at the end of the document after my bibliography. What to do ?

Comment: +1: The approach with the `rotating` package seems to work better with footnotes in the table (compared to `pdflscape`)!

Comment: +1: a concise solution that requires only one additional package.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

% An extra wide table 
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline

Object & Apple & Banana & Stone & Cake & Tree & Flower & House & Door & Car & Plane & Chair \\ \hline 

Quantity in Thousands & 35  &  25  & 23 & 33 & 43  & 52 & 64 & 75 & 86  & 94  & 122  \\ \hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}

%To this end, everything will be displayed in portrait format.\\
```

Comment: I have added the caption but its not working