# How to rotate a table?

Tags: tables, rotating

I have a table and I want to rotate it. The table has 3 rows and 4 columns, and I want to rotate the text inside this table as well. How can I do this?

Comment: please, for the love of god, **don't use `sidewaystable`s** unless you intend the document to be read while lying down. There's nothing more annoying than having to crane your neck to read a table in a pdf, use `lscape` or `pdflscape` so the table is rotated properly when shown on a monitor.

Comment: In relation to previous comment: see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19021/550) for rotating a floating table with `pdflscape`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As Jake said you can use `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package to rotate a table. This is perfectly fine for uncomplicated tables. However, this will read the whole table as macro argument which doesn't allow for verbatim or other special content and isn't that efficient.

As alternative you can use the `\adjustbox` macro or `adjustbox` environment from the `adjustbox` package (written by me). Both process the content as real box and not as macro argument as therefore avoids the mentioned drawbacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the very new package [`realboxes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/realboxes).
When loaded with the `graphicx` option (or without any but after `graphicx`) it provides `\Rotatebox` which works like `\rotatebox` but reads the content also as real box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}

\begin{document}

\Rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to get a caption on my table. How can I do that

Comment: @AaghazHussain: You can't place floats (`table`, `figure` etc.) inside boxes. You need to either place the `table` environment around the rotated box while placing the `\caption` inside it OR use a non-floating alternative like `\captionof` (see (Label and caption without float)[https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7210/2975]) or the `caption={the caption text},nofloat=table` keys when you use`adjustbox`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the caption but not rotated with the table and also I try to center the rotated table `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio,rotate=90,caption={Time taken in seconds}, float=table, center}`, but it is not centering.

Comment: @AaghazHussain: The order of keys is important. You can't center a float, you need to center the content of it. Do you really need a floating table here? Because if not, simply change `float=` to `nonfloat=` and move the `rotate` key just before the `center` key. It looks to me that you want it over the full page size right? Then you might want to wrap the whole thing into an `\afterpage{..}` (`afterpage` package) to place it on the next page. Maybe with `\clearpage` added before the `adjustbox`. Also you should check you width and height, as they are the dimensions BEFORE the rotate!

Comment: @AaghazHussain: If you still have issues don't hesitate to add a new question for your specific problem. Please add a link to this answer and state what is still missing and what you want to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 161):

Another option is to use `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Your caption here}
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can one change the direction of table using this method?

Comment: @Aymuos check on this interesting discussion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522866/208021 Maybe this helps you understanding how the `sidewaystable` package works.

Comment: `sidewaystable` automatically adjusts the direction of rotation for even and odd pages.

Comment: This didn't work!

Answer (score 77):

If all you want to do is rotate the complete table, but keep everything else on the page unrotated, you can use the `\rotatebox{<angle>}{ ... }` command from the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

However, if you have a large table that will take up the whole page, you might want to rotate the page instead of the table. You can do this using the `pdflscape` package if you're compiling with `pdflatex`, or `lscape` if you're using `latex`, which introduce a `landscape` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the landscape option is the best option: there's nothing more obnoxious than inserting a sideways table and forcing your reader to crane his neck just to read the pdf.

Comment: It is a nice option indeed. However in my document the page number is still in portrait mode, which makes it at the side of the page instead of at the bottom. Also, it doesn't disappear, no matter if I put a `\thispagestyle{empty}` before or after the `\begin{landscape}`. How to fix that?

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you want to rotate the table because it doesn't fit the width of a portrait page. Based on @Shep's comment to this question: use the `pdflscape` package ([CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape), [dtx](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdflscape.dtx), [pdf](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pdflscape.pdf)) by [Heiko Oberdiek](http://www.ctan.org/author/oberdiek).

> Package `pdflscape` adds PDF support to the environment `landscape` of
>   package `lscape` by setting the PDF page attribute `/Rotate`

I use Lyx, and it's in the FAQ: [How can I typeset certain pages of my documents in landscape mode?](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Output#landscape)

> Use the package `lscape` (or better `pdflscape`, which also supports pdflatex output).
>   Add to the preamble: `\usepackage{pdflscape}`
>   In the document, embrace the pages which should be in landscape mode by:
>
> ```
> \begin{landscape}
> ...
> \end{landscape}
> ```
>
> All other text will be in portrait mode pages. If you don't have the `pdflscape` package installed, get it from [ctan](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/)
>   The `lscape` package is part of the graphics bundle and should be installed by default.

Comment: Are you able to help with this question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298668/how-to-rotate-a-large-matrix-in-lyx) about rotating a large table in Lyx?

Comment: Even though I really like this solution, some printing services (such as [bod](http://bod.de/)) have issues with rotated pages. A check with your printing service is needed before using `landscape`.

Answer (score 8):

The `ctable` packages also has an option to rotate the table: `sideways`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}
\ctable[
caption={Your table caption},
label={tab:mytable},
botcap, % caption below table
sideways % This rotates the table
]
{ccc}
{
% Table footnotes here, see ctable docs
}
{
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 2, 1 & 2, 2     & 2, 3 \\
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very old post, but there is one more way to rotate a table is putting it inside a TikZ's handy `node`. The advantage is that you can use all options of `node`. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % >>> for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]  
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=90,transform shape,fill=yellow!30,inner sep=]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
First First & First Second\\
\hline
Second First & Second Second\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

From [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

[image]