# How to handle too many columns of table

Tags: tables

I need to print a table with many columns. I am thinking about two ways:

1. printed table like this (assume the paper only can print 6 dates at one row):

   ```
   Measure date1 date2 date3 date4 date5 date6
             1     2    3      4    5     6
          date 7 date8 date8 date10 date11 date12
            2       8    10    12    10     12
   ```

Here is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-Program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\zcolumn[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\linebreak[0]}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
VOID \\
AWAKE &
\begin{raggedright}
\zcolumn{5/31/16\\  a}
\zcolumn{6/1/16\\  b}
\zcolumn{6/2/16\\ c}
\zcolumn{6/3/16\\ d}
\zcolumn{6/4/16\\ e}
\zcolumn{6/5/16\\ a}
\zcolumn{6/6/16\\ b}
\zcolumn{6/7/16\\ c}
\zcolumn{6/8/16\\ d}
\zcolumn{6/9/16\\  e}
\zcolumn{6/10/16\\ d}
\zcolumn{6/11/16\\  e}
\zcolumn{6/12/16\\ d}
\zcolumn{6/13/16\\  e}

\end{raggedright}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

It prints this table correctly - date and value in one line and overflow to the next line

but when I apply the same logic to my real code, it prints the date and value vertically.

Can someone help on it?

My smallest real code:

```
%!TEX TS-Program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\sectionheader}[1] {
\textbf{#1}

\rule{\textwidth}{6pt}
}

\newcommand\zcolumn[1]{%
{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\linebreak[0]}}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.12em}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Patient Name: Claire  Roberts}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\sectionheader{SYMPTOMS}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\textbf{PERCEPTION}\\


    SATISFACTION &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ 2}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ 2}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline
\textbf{VOID}\\


    AWAKE &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ 5}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ 2}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ 1}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\SLEEPING &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ 5}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ 1}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\URGENCY &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ 2}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline
\textbf{UR}\\


    UR\_LEAK\_AMOUNT &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ Moderate}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\TOTAL &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ 1}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline
\textbf{BM}\\


    AWAKE &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ 3}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\SLEEPING &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ 5}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\SOIL\_AMOUNT &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline
\textbf{BOWEL}\\


    AMOUNT &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ 6}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ 5}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\TOTAL &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ 8}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ 9}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline
\textbf{PADS}\\


    TOTAL &

\begin{raggedright}



\zcolumn{5/31/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/1/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/2/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/3/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/4/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/5/16 \\ 9}

\zcolumn{6/6/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/7/16 \\ 8}

\zcolumn{6/8/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/9/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/10/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/11/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/12/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/13/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/14/16 \\ -}

\zcolumn{6/15/16 \\ -}
\end{raggedright}

\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\newpage


\bigskip

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26477/wider-tables-in-latex-which-is-the-best-solution)? The last one - hiding columns - might let you do it via method 2.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What's the paper size, and how wide is the text block of your document? Are the header cells literally `date1`, `date2` etc? If not, please provide a more realistic example. Incidentally, is typesetting the table in landscape mode an option for you?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete, small document which produces a problematic table when copy-paste-compiled into our editors so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RobertBrignall, I got my prototype code working, Here is my code:

Comment: No, you need to show an example that shows the *bad behaviour*. It's quite hard to guess what is wrong with code we cannot see, so you need to take your "real" code and reduce it to the smallest document that actually reproduces the problem you're describing, and add that code to your question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Could you let me know how can I post my smallest real code? It doesn't allow me to paste in comment since  it exceeds the size limitation. It also doesn't allow me to post in my original question since I don't have enough reputation to post extra link.

Comment: How did you post the code the code that is there now? You copied it from your editor, and pasted it into the question. Do the same.

Comment: After I deleted the image I posted before, I was able to post my real code. It would be better if I can post that image.

Comment: There is one crucial difference between the new code you posted and the old: You have a paragraph break (an empty line) between each `\zcolumn`. A paragraph break means a line break.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.Thanks so much! It works. I am a newbie of Latex. I have never thought that empty line in Latex does affect the page layout. There is another problem: I expect that this table printed on page#1, but it starts on page#2 and leave page#1 almost empty. Any suggestion?