# How can I rotate a large part of the page?

Tags: rotating

I'm trying to "hide" and answer by rotating it 180 degrees.

Using `\rotatebox` works fine if I have a short answer:

```
\rotatebox{180}{The answer is $\pi$}
```

However, if I want to put a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` or maybe rotate a whole paragraph I get errors:

```
\rotatebox{180}{
\begin{equation}
\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1 
\end{equation}
```

}
gives: `ERROR: Missing $ inserted.`

while

```
\rotatebox{180}{a

b

c
}
```

gives: `ERROR: Paragraph ended before \Grot@box@std was complete.`

Is there a better command to be using? or a way to make `\rotatebox` work for these cases?

PS. I tried using the `turn` environment of `rotating`, but while it compiled, it didn't give the desired outcome.

PPS. I tried using the packages listed in  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table)....to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `\vbox` (or a `\parbox` or a `minipage`) to box the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent\rotatebox{180}{\vbox{%
\begin{equation}
\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1
\end{equation}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `adjustbox` package for this:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{minibox=\textwidth,angle=180}
  % ...
\end{adjustbox}
```

It also support verbatim or other complex content.

Comment: that minibox was key. I didn't realize I need to use that. Thanks.