# how to rotate wide table in page thatnot outside of page

Tags: tables, rotating

My table is very wide and gets the outside of the page how to rotate table that placed landscape.

```
\begin{table}[!h]‎
‎\centering‎
‎\footnotesize‎
\caption{}\\‎
‎\label{tab11}‎ 
‎\begin{tabular}{ccccc}‎
‎\hline‎
\rl{‎‏AAAAAAAAAAAAA}&\rl{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}&\rl{CCCCCCCCCCCCCC}‎&‎‎$‎f[]‎$‎&‎$‎x‎$‎\\
‎\hline‎
$f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]=‎\frac{f[x_1,x_2,x_3]-f[x_0,x_1,x_2]}{x_3-x_0}‎‎$&$f[x_0,x_1,x_2]=‎\frac{f[x_1,x_2]-f[x_0,x_1]}{x_2-x_0}‎‎$‎‎&‎$f[x_0,x_1]=‎\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}‎‎‎$‎&$‎f[x_0]‎$‎&$‎x_0‎$‎‎\\‎‎
\\
$f[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]=‎\frac{f[x_2,x_3,x_4]-f[x_1,x_2,x_3]}{x_4-x_1}‎‎$&$f[x_1,x_2,x_3]=‎\frac{f[x_2,x_3]-f[x_1,x_2]}{x_3-x_1}‎‎$‎‎&‎$f[x_1,x_2]=‎\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}‎‎‎$‎&$‎f[x_1]‎$‎&$‎x_1‎$‎‎\\‎
‎\\
$‎‎$&$f[x_2,x_3,x_4]=‎\frac{f[x_3,x_4]-f[x_2,x_3]}{x_4-x_2}‎‎$‎‎&‎$f[x_2,x_3]=‎\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}‎‎‎$‎&$‎f[x_2]‎$‎&$‎x_2‎$‎‎\\‎‎
‎\\
$‎‎$&$‎‎$‎‎&‎$f[x_2,x_4]=‎\frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}‎‎‎$‎&$‎f[x_3]‎$‎&$‎x_3‎$‎‎\\‎
‎\\
‎$‎‎$&$‎‎$‎‎&‎$‎‎‎$‎&$‎f[x_4]‎$‎&$‎x_4‎$‎‎\\‎‎

‎\hline‎
 ‎\end{tabular}‎
‎\end{table}‎‎
```

Comment: How is the `\rl` macro defined?

Comment: Google says it's a command from ArabTeX.

Comment: have you seen [How to rotate a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25369)