# Rotate my table to be vertical

Tags: tables

I'm using the below script to rotate the table, but it keeps giving an error `l.208 \end{table}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} %AAB95
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{XThesis_TJBLACK} 
\usepackage{xtocinc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[active]{srcltx} \newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
{1.5 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.35\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering\hsize=.95\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape ess}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{mwe,subfig,calc}
\def\trans{^{\mathsf{T}}}
\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\newcommand{\rowname}[1]
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{#1}}
\usepackage{courier}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering
        \caption{Your caption here}
    \begin{tabular}{l|lllllll}
    \hline
    sssssssss/sssss ss ssssssssss & sssssssss & ssssssss & ssssssss                                   & sssssssssss                 & ssssssssss & sssssssss ssss sssssssss ssssssssss & sssssssss ssss sssssssss ssssssssssss \\ \hline
    sssss ssssssssssss            & sss       & sss      & sssssssss, ssssssssssss                    & sssssssss sssssss, sssssss  & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssssssss ssssssssssss        & sss       & ss       & sssssssss                                  & ssssss ssssss              & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssssss ssssssss             & ss        & sss      & sssssssss, sssssssss sssssssssss           & ssssssssssss, sssssssss    & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssss sssss                    & sss       & sss      & sssss, ssssssssss sssssss, ssssss ssssssss & ssssssssssss               & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    ssss                          & ss        & sss      & sssssss ssssss, sssssssss ssssssss         & sssssssss                  & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    sss                           & ss        & sss      & ssssssss ssssssssss                        & sssss sssssssss            & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssss ssssss                 & ss        & sss      & ssssssss ssssssssss                        & sssssssss ss sssss sssssss & sssssss    &                                     &                                        
    \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't try to nest a `sidewaystable` inside a `table`. Delete the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` instructions.

Comment: @Mico I've updated my question and I already did that but the same error appears. As I originally followed the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table but still the same problem

Comment: @Mico I think there is a problem with the `\usepackage{rotating}` as when I commented the table the error still appeared, but when I removed the package the file complied without errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, if you delete the two offending instructions, you should no longer be getting *errors*. You'll find that the table is just too wide to fit in the available space; while undesirable, it's not an "error". I suggest you peruse some of the answers to your earlier questions, e.g., regarding the sue of a `tabularx` environment, to find a way to make the table fit in the available space.

Comment: but why when I deleted the package the error no longer exists?

Comment: Please post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that actually generates the error(s) you say you're getting. Without an MWE, there's simply no way to tell what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23972/discussion-between-shepherd-and-mico).

Comment: no worries, I've updated my question, please have a look whenever you have the time to. I appreciate your kind assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- My TeX distribution doesn't feature the `XThesis_TJBLACK` and `xtocinc` packages; I've had to remove the corresponding `\usepackage` instructions to make your code compilable.
- It's generally not a good idea to manipulate the low-level TeX macro `\baselineskip` directly. Better to load the `setspace` package and to issue the directive `\setstretch{1.3}`. (Making this change will also avoid excessive spacing in footnotes and tables, where single-spacing should be used anyway.)
- If you want to use the `sidewaystable` environment, it's necessary to load the `rotating` package. (Aside: Since your code does not contain an `\end{table}` instruction, there is no way -- contrary to your claim -- that LaTeX can generate an error message containing the string `l.208 \end{table}`.)
- I don't get any compilation errors after I implement these changes. However, the table still won't fit inside the (rotated) text block, as you don't allow automatic line breaking. Consider using a `tabularx` environment instead of the basic `tabular` environment, and using a modified form of the `X` column type instead of the basic `l` column type.
- Don't use the `/` (forward slash) symbol if you want to allow linebreaks. Use `\slash` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} %AAB95
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newlfont}
%%\usepackage{XThesis_TJBLACK} 
%%\usepackage{xtocinc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage[active]{srcltx} 

%%\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
%%\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
%%\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
%%{\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
%%\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
%%{1.5 \defbaselineskip}}
%%\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.35\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering\hsize=.95\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape ess}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{mwe,subfig,calc}
\def\trans{^{\mathsf{T}}}
\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\newcommand{\rowname}[1]
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{#1}}
\usepackage{courier}

%% new:
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{rotating}  % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{array}     % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \centering
        \caption{Your caption here}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{x|*{7}{x}}
    \hline
    sssssssss\slash sssss ss ssssssssss & sssssssss & ssssssss & ssssssss                                   & sssssssssss                 & ssssssssss & sssssssss ssss sssssssss ssssssssss & sssssssss ssss sssssssss ssssssssssss \\ \hline
    sssss ssssssssssss            & sss       & sss      & sssssssss, ssssssssssss                    & sssssssss sssssss, sssssss  & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssssssss ssssssssssss        & sss       & ss       & sssssssss                                  & ssssss ssssss              & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssssss ssssssss             & ss        & sss      & sssssssss, sssssssss sssssssssss           & ssssssssssss, sssssssss    & ssssss     &                                     &                                         \\
    ssss sssss                    & sss       & sss      & sssss, ssssssssss sssssss, ssssss ssssssss & ssssssssssss               & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    ssss                          & ss        & sss      & sssssss ssssss, sssssssss ssssssss         & sssssssss                  & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    sss                           & ss        & sss      & ssssssss ssssssssss                        & sssss sssssssss            & sssssss    &                                     &                                         \\
    ssssss ssssss                 & ss        & sss      & ssssssss ssssssssss                        & sssssssss ss sssss sssssss & sssssss    &                                     &                                        
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but changing (commenting) the line spacing packages will affect my document right? as in my document I'm using this `\setlinespacing{1.3}`

Comment: shepherd - Try not to use `\setlinespacing{1.3}`; use `\setstretch{1.3}` instead. The `setspace` package provides macros named `\singlespacing` and `\doublespacing`, by the way.

Comment: I did that and I still get this error `\end{table}` I don't know why, although there is no `\end{table}` in this table definition (there are other tables)

Comment: @shepherd - The error has nothing to do with line spacing, right? If you keep getting an error about `\end{table}`, it has to be the case that there's an `\end{table}` instruction hanging around somewhere. Since you're not showing the code that produces the error, and since you're apparently unwilling to state the contents of the error message, I see no point in continuing this conversation. If you need to fix any remaining errors, by all means post a *new query* -- with a working Minimum Working Example that actually reproduces the error message(s) you say occur.

Comment: I'm happy to post the whole error, but I can't put the whole chapter of my thesis.

Comment: @shepherd - As I said, without an MWE that gives rise to the error, it's not promising to speculate as to what may be going on. If I were you, though, I would look for a missing `}` (right curly brace).

Comment: I'm sure that there is no missing `}` as when I comment the table and the `rotating` package it compile without any errors. I accepted your answer anyway for your kind assistance, I really appreciate your help.