# Landscape table and notes

Tags: tables, landscape, notes

Two questions

1. I have seven tables, two of them should be landscape instead of portrait. How do I make the landscape ones? What do I need to change/add to the below for the landscape tables?
2. I am trying to make the tables centered and the notes at the end not-centered. How do you do that?

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage {graphicx}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \begin{document}

 %table 1
 \begin{table}[htbp]
 \begin{threeparttable}
 \centering
   \caption{}
     \begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}

 \end{tabular}%
 \begin{tablenotes}
 \small
 \item Notes:  
 \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \label{tab:addlabel}%
 \end{table}%
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can landscape the whole page: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode

Comment: Or you can rotate the table: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table

Comment: Thanks. How can I make the notes after \item not centered and aligned with the left of the page