# How to rotate a large matrix in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, rotating

I have a large adjacency matrix in LyX.

**How can I rotate it to fit the page?**

[image]

*Alternative: you see that the commands such as the `\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}` are not interpreted as commands in Lyx. How to type them in Lyx?*
[image]

Comment: Are you asking what needs to be done to display the object in landscape more rather than in portrait mode?

Comment: @Mico whatever works. Both should work but unable to get any working, an instruction [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202183/2956) but not able to type the `\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}` in Lyx that it would interpret it as a command, see the photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on "Float: Table", click on "Settings", and check "Rotate sideways".

To insert custom LaTeX code in LyX (where you mention `\begin{landscape}`), go to Insert > TeX Code (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on Ubuntu). This is referred to as "ERT".

Answer (score 1):

The bottom page in the top picture (big table going over margins in sideways) is made with Lyx's option: click `Float: Table`, click on `Settings` and check `Rotate sideways` as instructed by scottkosty.

[image]

However I was not able to align the table properly with the default method so I ended up to the below method to manually specify the size that corresponds to the top page in the top picture.

[image]

[image]

*P.s. If you know how to encapsulate the handwritten code and the table block nicely in Lyx in its GUI, please let me know. This curiosity moved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299137/encapsulation-of-latex-code-and-lyx-table-block-nicely).*

Comment: For your "P.s.", it is possible to create a new (local) layout, see the Customization manual (or maybe open a new question for more details).

Comment: @G.M. Thank you, moved the question and curiosity [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299137/encapsulation-of-latex-code-and-lyx-table-block-nicely).