# Importing large dataset with many macros and large table to LyX?

Tags: lyx, import

I want to import a large dataset to Lyx below, I currently compile it in Textmate. What is the most convenient way to import all macros and the table to LyX only for this document?

[image]

Comment: Also you may know the answer to this large table management issue in Lyx [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298668/how-to-rotate-a-large-matrix-in-lyx).

Comment: An alternative, possibly less painful option would be  to keep the table in LaTeX and just `input` it into the LyX document. You won't be able to edit it within LyX, though, but that may be less of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the LaTeX code that belongs in the preamble, just copy/paste it into Document > Settings > LaTeX preamble. For the actual table, copy the LaTeX to the clipboard and then go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX. Note that this does not always work well because parsing arbitrary LaTeX (to convert it into LyX's internal format) is quite a difficult task.