# Rotation in LYX package

Tags: lyx, packages, rotating

Hey I am using Lyx and would like to use to rotate a table because it does not fit my page.

I used the below link to rotate however when running the programming an error occured . 
[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298668/how-to-rotate-a-large-matrix-in-lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298668/how-to-rotate-a-large-matrix-in-lyx)

[image]

Can someone guide me how can I solve this please?

Comment: Please add a MWE that reproduces this problem. Welcome to TEXSE.

Comment: @Raaja - Thanks for welcoming me. What is a MWE?

Comment: @Lise see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Sorry for late response. I was travelling.

Comment: @scottkosty - thank you for your response.

Comment: @Raaja it seems I cannot attached the file here :(

Comment: @Lise its unclear why, may be you can try seeing other examples.

Comment: Hi, I managed all I need to do is use the landscape package and add an ERT. Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode

Comment: `rotfloat.sty` not found means that the `rotfloat` package is not installed, use the package manager of your TeX distribution to install it.