# how to flip a table

Tags: tables

because the table does not fit in the page fields how can I overwrite the table?

that is, the word "ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ" remains on the top of page but the table is rotated for 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: OT: you mean like this? https://media.giphy.com/media/sIE0hveuiwCNG/giphy.gif ? (SCNR ;) )

Comment: Duplicate from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25369/46718 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

since you not provide any code nor minimal working example, i use one of my tables' examples, so you should replace text and table with yours:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent1em\hangafter1\relax}X}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{table}[htb]
\hfil
\begin{sideways}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textheight}% allowed size at default float/text ratio
\captionof{table}{table title}
\label{tab:sideway}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{P
    *{4}{S[table-format=3.3]}}%c|c|c|c|
                                        \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Concept}}
                                    \\  \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Critères d'évaluations}
    &   {\thead{Perfomance}}
        &   {\thead{Économie}}
            &   {\thead{Légèreté}}
                &   {\thead{Simplicité}}
                                    \\ \midrule
Précision des images thermiques [mK]
    & 50 & 100 & 65 & 65            \\
Résolution spatiale [mm]
    & 19 & 3.3 & 19 & 19            \\
Stockage des données [To]
    & 4 & 8 & 4 & 12                \\
Résolution temporelle des images thermiques [fps]
    & 60 & 64 & 50 & 50             \\
Signal de sortie de la caméra thermique [bits]
    & 16 & {bites me} & 14 & 14     \\
Coût total de production [\$]
    & \num{70 744} & \num{13 920} & \num{24 128} & \num{67 130}
                                    \\  \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

note: to have wider table you should change default ratio between text and floats on the page.