# Creating a large table in one without overlapping text in latex

Tags: tables, two-column

[image]I have used the following code to create a large table with vertical column names. However, the table overlapped on my text. I need to have a table on the whole page. I appreciate any help about this as I am working on my paper.

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcolumntype{P}[2]{%
  >{\begin{turn}{#1}\begin{minipage}{#2}\small\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}l%
  <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    %   \centering
      \caption{Some properties}
      \label{tab:test1}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}rcccccccccccccccccc@{}}
       \toprule
      & \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}}{Feedback} &
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}}{Adaptation} &
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Challenging Assessment Methods}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Collaborative Learning}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Authentic \& Challenging Goals}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Inquiry-Based LEarning}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Use of Multimedia}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Multi vs. Single users}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Visibilitiy of System Status}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Sense of Presence}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Matching with Real-world}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{User Control \& Freedom}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Consistency \& Standards}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Error Prevention}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Recognition Rather than Recall}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Flexible and ease of use}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{High Representational Fidelity}\\
         \midrule
        Babich et al.\cite{Babich2004} & N & N & N & N & N & N& N & X & X & N & N & N & N& X & N & N & N & N\\
    %   System 2 & X & X & X \\
    %   System 3 & X &    & X \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please edit your example so it is a complete document people can run, as it is we do not know what a `P` column is, or the size of your page so it is impossible to help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comment I edited my post.

Comment: You declared a total of 19 columns but used 20. In order to get rid of the error message, you will have to add another column: `\begin{tabular}{@{}rccccccccccccccccccc@{}}` or shorter: `\begin{tabular}{@{}r*{19}{c}@{}}`. Nevertheless, I'd suggest to switch the page orientation to landscape as the table is now too wide for the page.

Comment: @leandriis I applied your command but the table is still overlapping on the text.

Comment: `table*` instead ot `table` should help.

Comment: Yes, you can change the orientation of a specific page using the `landscape` environment. Other possibilities might be found here: [How to rotate a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25369/134144). If you want to keep your table on a portrait page, you might want to allow the header row to be a bit taller (replace {1.6cm}` by `{3.25cm}` and your table's width will no longer exceed teh textwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table will perfectly fit in portrait orientation provided you take a larger height for the column heads and a smaller value for `\tabcolsep`, and use the `table*` environment. I did so using the `\rothead` command from `makecell` for its much simpler syntax. Last, I used the `tabularx` environment, and the `X` type for the first column;

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
 \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\setlength\rotheadsize{3.2cm}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \caption{Some properties}
  \label{tab:test1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{19}{c}@{}}
   \toprule
  & \rothead{Feedback} &
    \rothead{Adaptation} &
    \rothead{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
    \rothead{Challenging Assessment Methods}&
    \rothead{Collaborative Learning}&
    \rothead{Authentic \& Challenging Goals}&
    \rothead{Inquiry-Based LEarning}&
    \rothead{Use of Multimedia}&
    \rothead{Multi vs. Single users}&
    \rothead{Visibilitiy of System Status}&
    \rothead{Sense of Presence}&
    \rothead{Matching with Real-world}&
    \rothead{User Control \& Freedom}&
    \rothead{Consistency \& Standards}&
    \rothead{Error Prevention}&
    \rothead{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
    \rothead{Recognition Rather than Recall}&
    \rothead{Flexible and ease\\ of use}&
    \rothead{High Representational Fidelity}\\
     \midrule
    Babich et al.\cite{Babich2004} & N & N & N & N & N & N& N & X & X & N & N & N & N& X & N & N & N & N\\
% System 2 & X & X & X \\
% System 3 & X & & X \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard for your solution it perfectly fits to my document without any error!

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I have added the missing column specifier, replaced `table` by `table*` to prevent the table from overlapping the text and used a taller header row in combination with a slightly decreased `\tabcolsep` in order to make the table narrow enough to fit into the page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{P}[2]{%
  >{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#2}\small\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}l%
  <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}

\newcommand{\myrothead}{\multicolumn{1}{P{90}{3.25cm}}}



\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum \lipsum
    \begin{table*}
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.9pt}
      \caption{Some properties}
      \label{tab:test1}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}r*{19}{c}@{}}
       \toprule
      & \myrothead{Feedback} &
        \myrothead{Adaptation} &
        \myrothead{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \myrothead{Challenging Assessment Methods}&
        \myrothead{Collaborative Learning}&
        \myrothead{Authentic \& Challenging Goals}&
        \myrothead{Inquiry-Based LEarning}&
        \myrothead{Use of Multimedia}&
        \myrothead{Multi vs. Single users}&
        \myrothead{Visibilitiy of System Status}&
        \myrothead{Sense of Presence}&
        \myrothead{Matching with Real-world}&
        \myrothead{User Control \& Freedom}&
        \myrothead{Consistency \& Standards}&
        \myrothead{Error Prevention}&
        \myrothead{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \myrothead{Recognition Rather than Recall}&
        \myrothead{Flexible and ease of use}&
        \myrothead{High Representational Fidelity}\\
         \midrule
        Babich et al.\cite{Babich2004} & N & N & N & N & N & N& N & X & X & N & N & N & N& X & N & N & N & N\\
    %   System 2 & X & X & X \\
    %   System 3 & X &    & X \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on how many entries (rows your final table will have, you could also consider transposing the table. This might make the quite long column headers more easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. As @leandriis mentioned in the comment, the width of the table is big so I needed to change the direction to landscape. At the end, code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcolumntype{P}[2]{%
  >{\begin{turn}{#1}\begin{minipage}{#2}\small\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}l%
  <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    %   \centering
      \caption{Some properties}
      \label{tab:test1}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}rcccccccccccccccccc@{}}
       \toprule
      & \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}}{Feedback} &
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}}{Adaptation} &
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Challenging Assessment Methods}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Collaborative Learning}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Authentic \& Challenging Goals}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Inquiry-Based LEarning}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Use of Multimedia}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Multi vs. Single users}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Visibilitiy of System Status}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Sense of Presence}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Matching with Real-world}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{User Control \& Freedom}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Consistency \& Standards}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Error Prevention}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Previous Knowledge Construction}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Recognition Rather than Recall}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{Flexible and ease of use}&
        \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{1.6cm}@{}}{High Representational Fidelity}\\
         \midrule
        Babich et al.\cite{Babich2004} & N & N & N & N & N & N& N & X & X & N & N & N & N& X & N & N & N & N\\
    %   System 2 & X & X & X \\
    %   System 3 & X &    & X \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code still results in the [already mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501461/creating-a-large-table-in-one-without-overlapping-text-in-latex#comment1266496_501461)  error message `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`