# Table rotating as landscape by sidewaystable

Tags: tables, rotating

I am writing the thesis and i have a problem with a long table which is not possible to write it horizontally and i need to rotate it to write as landscape. This is the main table in paper format:

[image]

and i am trying to write it in landscape mode. The latex text to do this in my thesis format is:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            \vertsp Parameter \vertsp Planck high-$\ell$+$\tau_{\rm prior}$ \vertsp Planck TTTEEE \vertsp Planck high-$\ell$+$\tau_{\rm prior}$+BKP \vertsp Planck TTTEEE+BKP \\
            \hline\hline
            \morehorsp
            n = 1   \vertsp N \vertsp $ 41^{+5}_{-7} $ \vertsp $ 50^{+5}_{-9} $\vertsp $ 43^{+4}_{-6} $  \vertsp $ 51^{+5}_{-9} $ \\
            \vertsp $ \xi $ \vertsp $ 0.0003^{+0.0014}_{-0.0006} $ \vertsp $ 0.0009^{+0.0007}_{-0.0003} $ \vertsp $ 0.0009^{+0.0007}_{-0.0005} $ \vertsp $ 0.0009^{+0.0006}_{-0.0004} $ \\
            \vertsp $ n_s $ \vertsp $ 0.962\pm 0.005 $ \vertsp $ 0.966\pm 0.005 $ \vertsp $ 0.961\pm 0.005 $ \vertsp $ 0.966\pm 0.005$ \\
            \vertsp $ n_{\rm run} $ \vertsp $ -0.0009^{+0.0004}_{-0.0002} $ \vertsp $ -0.0006^{+0.0002}_{-0.0001} $ \vertsp $ -0.0008\pm{-0.0002} $ \vertsp $ -0.0006^{+0.0002}_{-0.0001} $\\   
            \vertsp $ r $ \vertsp $ < 0.213 $ \vertsp $ < 0.100 $ \vertsp $ < 0.106 $ \vertsp $ <0.081 $\\
            \vertsp $ \chi^2 $ \vertsp $ 2453 $ \vertsp $ 12992 $ \vertsp $ 2495 $ \vertsp $ 12992 $\\
            \hline\hline
            \morehorsp
            n = 2/3\vertsp N \vertsp $ 36^{+6}_{-7} $ \vertsp $ 45^{+6}_{-8} $ \vertsp $ 38^{+4}_{-6} $ \vertsp $ 45^{+5}_{-8} $ \\
            \vertsp $ \xi $ \vertsp $ 0.0000^{+0.0016}_{-0.0006} $ \vertsp $ 0.0008^{+0.0008}_{-0.0003} $ \vertsp $ 0.0006^{+0.0008}_{-0.0005} $ \vertsp $ 0.0007^{+0.0007}_{-0.0004}$ \\
            \vertsp $ n_s $ \vertsp $ 0.961\pm {0.005}$ \vertsp $ 0.966^{+0.005}_{-0.004} $ \vertsp $ 0.961\pm{0.005} $ \vertsp $ 0.966\pm 0.005$ \\
            \vertsp $ n_{\rm run} $\vertsp $ -0.0011^{+0.0007}_{-0.0002} $ \vertsp $ -0.0006^{+0.0003}_{-0.0001} $ \vertsp $ -0.0009^{+0.0004}_{-0.0002} $ \vertsp $ -0.0006^{+0.0003}_{-0.0001} $ \\   
            \vertsp $ r $ \vertsp $ < 0.188 $ \vertsp $ < 0.094 $  \vertsp $ <0.101 $ \vertsp $ <0.077 $\\
            \vertsp $ \chi^2 $ \vertsp $ 2452 $ \vertsp $ 12949 $ \vertsp $ 2495 $ \vertsp $ 12992 $\\
            \hline\hline
            \morehorsp
            n = 4/3\vertsp N \vertsp $ 46^{+4}_{-6} $ \vertsp $ 55^{+5}_{-10} $ \vertsp $ 47^{+4}_{-6} $ \vertsp $ 55^{+5}_{-9} $\\
            \vertsp $ \xi $ \vertsp $ 0.0004^{+0.0013}_{-0.0006} $ \vertsp $ 0.0011^{+0.0007}_{-0.0003} $ \vertsp $ 0.0011^{+0.0006}_{-0.0004} $ \vertsp $0.0011\pm{0.0005}$ \\
            \vertsp $ n_s $ \vertsp $ 0.962\pm 0.005$ \vertsp $ 0.966\pm 0.005 $ \vertsp $ 0.961\pm 0.005$ \vertsp $ 0.966\pm 0.005 $ \\
            \vertsp $ n_{\rm run} $ \vertsp $ -0.0009\pm{0.0003} $ \vertsp $ -0.0006^{+0.0002}_{-0.0001} $ \vertsp $ -0.0008\pm{0.0002} $ \vertsp $-0.0006^{+0.0002}_{-0.0001}$\\   
            \vertsp $ r $ \vertsp $ < 0.215 $ \vertsp $ < 0.106 $ \vertsp $ <0.108 $ \vertsp $ < 0.082 $ \\
            \vertsp $ \chi^2 $ \vertsp $ 2454 $  \vertsp $ 12950 $ \vertsp $ 2495 $ \vertsp $ 12992$\\
            \bottomrul
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Constraints on cosmological and inflationary parameters in case of power-law potentials with non-minimal coupling from Planck and Planck+BKP datasets. Constraints on parameters are at the $68 \% $ C.L.  (upper limits at $95 \%$ C.L.)  }
    \label{Table1}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

but in the output, everything is mixed without any discipline as:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could post a *compilable* code, no just a snippet?

Comment: I think a `\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}` around the table should do the trick.    [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25387/194523)

Comment: How you defined `\vertsp`? it seems that you try to replace ampersands with them. Apparently your (unknown) definition has error(s). Also use of `\rm` in LaTeX code is deprecate. Better is define new commands `\prior` as : `\newcommand\prior{\mathrm{prior}}` etc.  For more suggestions/help please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete self contained document.

Comment: `sidewaystable` will set the material in the order input.  If you want the caption at the top, input it before the tabular (and also before the `\centering`).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))