# How to rotate a Markdown table to landscape? Solutions I've tried print the markup instead of the rendered table

Tags: xetex, pdf, landscape, pandoc

I'm using Markdown to create a PDF via xelatex and pandoc. Here's my command line:

```
pandoc -s combined.markdown --from markdown+table_captions+auto_identifiers --filter mermaid-filter.cmd --pdf-engine=xelatex -o combined.pdf
```

My document contains the following table:

```
Table: Groups and Access Rights - Global

| Group Name                  | Type      | Config / Func   | Default Act | Reqs     | Derog    | ADC      | Haz      | Chg      | BS         | Risks    | MMSP Status |
| :-------------------------- | --------- | --------------- | ----------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- | -------- | ----------- |
| CPxxx Risk Managers         | \gls{ps}  | X               | CPxxx Home  |          |          |          |          |          |            |          |             |
(etc)
```

It's very wide, so I want to render it in landscape.
I've tried using {rotating}, {lscape}, and {pdflscape}, but they all look like this:
[image]

Is there any way to make this work? Is it something to do with the order of packages?

Comment: If you have a PDF, use the [rotate] option of \includegraphics (graphicx package).

Comment: (for markdown environment) – The issue is `markdown` environment is verbatim, see [rotating - How to rotate a table? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table) (use `\Rotatebox`) and [How to use markdown in todonotes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625548/how-to-use-markdown-in-todonotes) (use `\cprotect`). (although those are direct LaTeX instead of pandoc)

Answer (score 3):

I found following solution:

````
---
title: "Doc-Title"
lang: "de"
colorlinks: true
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
  \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
    ```
...
````

in your markdown use:

```
    \blandscape
    
    |header1|header2|header3|
    |:------|:------|------:|
    |LINE1  | VAL 1 |  1.00 |
    |Line2  | val 2 |  2.07 |
    |Line3  | val 3 |  3.14 |
    
    \elandscape
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaTeX chunks inside Markdown, but not markdown inside LaTeX.

In the markdown to LaTeX conversion, what it is  inside a command argument or an LaTeX environment is simply ignored (On the other hand, note that  the Markdown table is converted to a LaTeX `longtable`, that could not be used in some conditions (e.g., in two columns documents).

One solution could be first export only the Markdown table and then copy & paste (or `\input`) the LaTeX code (of the longtable only) in the rotating environment.

Other, more convenient, is to write the nesting environment with the Markdown syntax:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:  
- \usepackage{lscape}  
---


::::::::{.landscape data-latex=""}

11 12 13
-- -- --
21 22 23
31 32 33

::::::::
```

Removing irrelevant code in the LaTeX output, the above should be equivalent to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
11 & 12 & 13\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
21 & 22 & 23\tabularnewline
31 & 32 & 33\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what the ":::{}" parts do? I've searched around and can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: They are simply the landscape environment in `rmarkdown` syntax. See   https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html

Comment: I don't have R or RMarkdown installed, so I think I'll try a different route. Thanks