How can I rotate a table when generating a PDF from markdown with pandoc?
I want to generate a PDF from a Markdown file using a Latex template and pandoc with lualatex as latex engine. The md file contains text and a rather large table. I want the table to be printed on a separate page and rotatated 90 degrees, so it fits the page. I saw solutions where they just put the page with the table in landscape, but this is not what I want. The page should stay in portrait with the table rotated.
I tried achieving this using latex blocks in the markdown file like this:
```{=latex}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{
` ``
    
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| This     | is       | the      |
| content  | of my    | table    |
    
```{=latex}
}
\end{table}
\newpage 
`` `

But this produces the error: Error producing PDF ! Missing \endgroup inserted. <inserted text> \endgroup l.569 }
I also tried to use one latex block only with the markdown table included. This produces a pdf and also rotated the content. The problem is, the table is not recognized as a table and just printed as a single line of text.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this since I'm new to pandoc and don't really know where to find a solution for this.
Thanks

This question is similar to: How to rotate a Markdown table to landscape? Solutions I've tried print the markup instead of the rendered table. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you don't want to rotate the page, have a look at the adjustbox solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25387/36296

I used the sidwaystable solution and it worked, thanks!
