# Place a table on a new landscape page in a two column paper

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, landscape

Very related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t/19021?noredirect=1#comment463452_19021) and some of the comments therein, I need to insert a landscape page for a wide table, in a two column document.

As suggested there, I have tried to use

```
\afterpage{%
\clearpage
```

so that the floats were supposed to be flushed in a proper way, but this is not the case. The document still show wrong disposal of the floats and/or blank parts.
I don't know exactly what information I should add here, but I hope this gives the general sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `lscape` and `pdflscape` packages (`lscape` is required by `pdflscape`).

I'm not sure if you'll need to switch to single column first, if so, I'd do it before and after the `landscape` commands. Without a MWE from you I'm assuming you use `multicols`. Before the code below I'd put `\end{multicols}` and after the text below I'd restart the multiple columns with `\begin{multicols}{2}`

I use something like the below to have a figure page rotated sideways in a PDF document. Not only is the figure rotated, but the page is readable in the resulting PDF.

```
\begin{landscape} % begin the rotated content.
\begin{figure} % begin content to include on rotated page.
\begin{centering} % Centre the content (not required), personal preference
\includegraphics{some.pdf} % The acutal content
\par\end{centering} % end the centring (remove if \begin{centering} not used)

\protect\caption{\label{fig:aFig}Some PDF Fig} %figure caption

\end{figure} % end of content
\end{landscape} % end rotating
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please comment your code? So I can grab what the lines do. For example, it would be great if you can indicate which line switch off the `two-column` mode. Also, in my case I need to print a table: do you think it is different from a `figure` case?

Comment: I have also found the environment `\begin{sidewaystable*}` to be useful. Do you think it can be of general interest?

Comment: I've never used it. I wanted the page rotated in the output.