# How to rotate the large table and caption?

Tags: tables

I want to rotate a large table with the caption. However, I can not rotate the caption for the table. Do you have any ideas how to rotate the caption for this layout? Thanks a lot.

Here my text code is below

```
\rotatebox{90}{
% \caption{Comparison} I cannot use this function like that
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
\hline
Names  & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\hline
Jobs   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
Types   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    
}
```

Comment: Real quick: Why did you set the tags `biblatex` and `table-of-contents`?

Comment: You can not use the standard `\caption`-command outside of floats (`figure` or `table`).

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your comment. I will remove the tags as you suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
\hline
Names  & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\hline
Jobs   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
Types   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

While iacopo's answer is the way I'd choose, here is a different solution:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{
\vbox{
    \centering
    \captionaboveof{table}{Comparison}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
    \hline
    Names  & A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
    \hline
    Jobs   & A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
    Types   & A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}    
}
}
\end{document}
```

If you don't use a KOMA-class you can use the package `caption` and replace `\captionaboveof` with `\captionof`.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative option to the previous two, for really large tables I prefer to rotate the whole page instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{%
\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
\hline
Names  & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\hline
Jobs   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
Types   & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage% Flush page
}
\end{document}
```

This has the advantage that the page displays correctly in software and prints like normal with headers and footers in normal orientation. It really depends on your requirements.

[image]

(credit to Martin Scharrer for [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19021/44049))