# Listing in landscape table

Tags: tables, pdftex, landscape, lstlisting

I am relatively new to LaTex and I am trying to add a single landscape table to my document. I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t) and the given `\afterpage` example works great in my environment. However as soon as I try to insert a listing into my table, I am no longer able to compile the file. Here's the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{frame=none,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=0mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{
     \clearpage
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \begin{landscape}
         \centering
         \begin{tabular}{llll}
           \hline
           A & B & C &
           \begin{lstlisting}
           public int add(int a, int b){
             int sum = a + b;
             return sum;
           }
           \end{lstlisting}
           \\
           \hline
         \end{tabular}
         \captionof{table}{Table caption}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

The error I get when running `pdflatex` is:

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.103 \newpage
              {\pagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage}
?
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: please extend your code sniped to complete document, which we can compile as it is, i.e. beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listings` can not be used in the argument of another command (a general restriction of verbatim-like commands) but the command `\afterpage` here is doing nothing so you can simply delete it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=none,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=0mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\usepackage{xcolor}% missing
\begin{document}


     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \begin{landscape}
         \centering
         \begin{tabular}{llll}
           \hline
           A & B & C &
           \begin{lstlisting}
           public int add(int a, int b){
             int sum = a + b;
             return sum;
           }
           \end{lstlisting}
           \\
           \hline
         \end{tabular}
         \captionof{table}{Table caption}
    \end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you're right this works. However I have some text before and after the table and that's why i need the `\afterpage`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @HolySeven I wouldn't use `\afterpage` except as a last resort (and I  wrote it:-) and having any command around `listings` stops you using listings,  You can always just place the `landscape` environment at the right place manually.

Comment: @David_Carlisle okay thanks. I am not entirely happy with it, but I guess I have no other choice.

Comment: @HolySeven oh there are always other choices in a system like tex:-) The above is almost certainly what I'd do (and afterpage, landscape and longtable are all my code) but if you really need listings in the argument of another command use the listings file input form rather than having the code fragment inline in your main document, having it in a file protects the catcode changes and it is far more robust.

Comment: @David_Carlisle that did the trick. I was unaware of the `\lstinputlisting` option. Thanks a lot!