# How to control the postion of a table

Tags: tables, positioning

I have a table like this:

```
\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
\newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
\newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
\newcommand{\rr}{{\rm r}}
\newcommand{\pp}{{\rm p}}
\newcommand{\AAA}{{\rm A}}
\newcommand{\rev}{{\rm {rev}}}
\newcommand{\VV}{{\rm V}}
\newcommand{\PP}{{\rm P}}
\newcommand{\bb}{{\rm b}}
\newcommand{\cc}{{\rm c}}
\newcommand{\II}{{\rm I}}
\newcommand{\inff}{{\rm {inf}}}
\newcommand{\baru}{\bar{u}}
\newcommand{\barv}{\bar{v}}
\newcommand{\barw}{\bar{w}}
\newcommand{\barp}{\bar{p}}
\newcommand{\barU}{\bar{U}}
\newcommand{\barV}{\bar{V}}
\newcommand{\barW}{\bar{W}}
\newcommand{\barP}{\bar{P}}
\newcommand{\hu}{\hat{u}}
\newcommand{\hv}{\hat{v}}
\newcommand{\hw}{\hat{w}}
\newcommand{\hp}{\hat{p}}
\newcommand{\difp}[3][2]{\frac{\partial #2}{\partial #3}}



\begin{table}[t!]
         %%---------------------------
%             \centering
            \subfloat[P1]{
            \begin{tabular}{|c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c |c|}
              \hline
              Caso & $\omega_\ii$ & $\PP_{\II\bb}$ & $\PP_{\II\II\bb}$ 
              & $\PP_{\II\cc}$ & $\PP_{\II\II\cc}$ & $\PP_{\II\bb} + \PP_{\II\II\bb}$ & $\PP_{\II\cc} + \PP_{\II\II\cc}$ &
              $U_\rev$ & $y_\dd/y_\inff$ \\
              \hline
          D=3.00 B=-0.35 & 0.02 & 0.069 & 0.0080 & 0.032 & 0.045 & 0.077 & 0.077 & -0.28 & 1.33 \\
          D=3.00 B=-0.15 & -0.053 & 0.0040 & -0.011 & -0.017 & 0.0095 & -0.007 & -0,007 & -0.14 & 0.62 \\
          D=5.00 B=-0.35 & 0.0095 & 0.064 & 0.015 & 0.033 & 0.046 & 0.079 & 0.079 & -0.18 & 1.23 \\ 
          D=5.00 B=-0.15 & -0.027 & -0.019 & 0.030 & -0.017 & 0.028 & 0.011 & 0.011 & -0.056 & 0.79 \\
          D=9.00 B=-0.35 & 0.0061 & 0.082 & 0.021 & 0.044 & 0.060 & 0.103 & 0.104 & -0.20 & 1.21 \\
          D=9.00 B=-0.15 & -0.0072 & -0.029 & 0.10 & -0.010 & 0.089 & 0.071 & 0.079 & -0.096 & 0.95 \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular}
            }
            \end{table}
```

My final result is:

[image]

The page is cutting the table. How to fix this?

Comment: Narrow down your table by rearranging the data if possible. Or make [the table, a landscape one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t).

Comment: please extend your table code to complete small document that we can see your page layout and your commands definitions. table as is not possible to compile