# Landscape tables: can I use \toprule inside \afterpage{}?

Tags: tables, landscape, afterpage

I'm experimenting with landscape tables.
I came accross [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t) question, and I'm trying to modify it to get fancier tables.
I would like to use commands like `\toprule`, to draw horizontal lines.

Here's my take:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            A & B & C & D \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Which unfortunately does not compile.

I get the following error:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 25.
! Undefined control sequence.
\AP@ ...centering \begin {tabular}{llll} \toprule 
                                                  A & B & C & D \\ \bottomru...
l.25 \end
         {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \bottomrule 

l.25 \end
         {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any idea tosolve this?
I also would like to use tabularx package in a similar fashion.

Best,
Andrea

Comment: If I add the `booktabs` package to the preamble, the code compiles just fine on my computer.

Comment: @a_bet did the answer meet your requirement

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved by comment: OP forgot to load booktabs package.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{booktabs}%<-----------------------------------ADD
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
    \lipsum % Text before
%   \afterpage{%
%       \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
%       \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
        \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
            \centering % Center table
            \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllll}
                \toprule
                A & B & C & D&&&&&&X&Y&&&&&& \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
        \end{landscape}
        \clearpage% Flush page
%   }
    \lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why? 
In my other document where I use regular tables I don't need that to use `\toprule`

Comment: @a_bet, please show us an example of document with table, which use rules defined in the `booktabs` package without loading it.

Comment: @a_bet in other tables normally `\hline` is used but with addition of package booktabs the horizontal lines are customized and visually better-- please read the documentation -- request accept the answer if it meets your stated requirement