# sidewaysfigure and landscape

Tags: pdf, rotating, landscape

I have some figures which I wish to display in landscape, with rotated captions.

I can achieve this fine using the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package.

I want to also ensure that the PDF document automatically displays in the right orientation for the reader.I can achieve this using the `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package.

I can't however seem to combine both of these for the effect I want. If I try encapsulating the `sidewaysfigure` in the `landscape` environment I get my graphic rotated 180 degrees (the page does display in the right orientation on screen however).

```
\afterpage{\begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{image}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{landscape}}
```

Doesn't work - figure displays incorrectly.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{image}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Figure displays correctly, but PDF document doesn't recognise that this page is landscape so displays automatically in portrait when viewed on-screen.

Comment: As of the documentation of the `rotating` package, the `sidewaysfigure` environment does already do the rotation depending on an even or odd page number. Maybe this feature was introduced later, but this package should be doing everything you want right now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't use sidewaysfigure within landscape - it will turn your figure twice. A regular figure should suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{image}
  \caption{caption}
  \label{fig:label}
 \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I feel silly now. I thought I'd tried that. I needed to add some resizing options and play around. In the end [width=0.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio] worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This solution will not float the landscape page, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471472/36836 for a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Although this question was seemingly answered (by @Bettina) over a year ago, I think that the complexity of the question and answer is misleading. There are two potential problems in the proposed solution:

1. If the landscape page is placed amongst other floats, it doesn't behave nicely
2. If the landscape page has other headers/footers, it doesn't behave nicely

I will link some helpful threads:

- [Wrapping text around landscape environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-wrap-text-around-landscape-page/11473#11473)
- [A follow-up post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t)
- [How to clear the header/footers of landscape pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages)
- [How to deal with other floats around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/force-floats-to-be-typeset-after-their-occurrence-in-the-source-text)

I think the following example illustrates how to put everything together. It works for my purposes, and the other floats around the document seem to flow properly. Now it uses the `flafter` package which forces floats to appear after their declaration in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{lscape}{% 
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[LO] {}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{
\clearpage% To flush out all floats, might not be what you want
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{lscape}
\pagestyle{lscape}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myfigure.pdf}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, and found a fix.

Preamble of  original file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Fix:

```
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
%\usepackage{rotating}
```

So insert `\RequirePackage{rotating}` BEFORE `\documentclass`, and remove `\usepackage{rotating}`