# Sideways picture shown on wrong page

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating

My picture and my section won't be on the same page. I have tried the float package with `[H]` and `[!]` and so on but it won't work

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}
\newpage

  \appendix

    \section{LabVIEW-kod}
      \begin{sidewaysfigure}[h]
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{lab_12.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:big_uppgift}
      \end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

**Note from editor**

Added packages `rotating` and `pdflscape` as I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159988/sidewaysfigure-and-landscape) to recover from `environment sidewaysfigure undefined`, and of course I have gotten a file not found error, so I looked for how to use example images, and I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738/example-images-in-latex), and therefore added `mwe` and used the examples. Here is the resulting output:

[image]

(p. 1)

[image]

(p. 2)

Comment: @ArunDebray Isn't this question asking the opposite i.e. how to put it on the current page rather than a new one?

Comment: @cfr: thank you; that was my mistake. I've retracted my vote. (It's still likely that this has been asked before, though.)

Comment: @ArunDebray I agree, but it needs to be marked as a duplicate of a question which asks the same thing ;).

Comment: @cfr I have searched for an answer but didn't find one that said something that helped. The response is often use \usepackage{float} and use [H]
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps it is just too large for the space? That is the most common reason, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix some text (section title) and `sidewaysfigure` on the same page.  In your case, if the image is shorter than rest of vertical place on the page and you like to have both on the same page, just can rotate only image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{LabVIEW-kod}
      \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[height=0.85\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:big_uppgift}
      \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, in this case figure caption is not rotated width image.

Comment: You can have a rotated caption by putting the image and \caption inside a \parbox or minipage and rotating the whole thing.  It helps to know how wide the image is first.