# How to fit sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure in one page

Tags: tables, floats, rotating, sidewaystable, sidewaysfigure

I want to put one `sidewaystable` and one `sidewaysfigure` in one page to save page space. However, according to [this link](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/sidewaysfloats.html), these sideways floats always placed on a page of its own. I am wondering if there is any technique that achieves the same effect, while not necessarily adopting the "sideways" approach?

Comment: You can use the `landscape` environment for that.

Comment: For example, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159988/sidewaysfigure-and-landscape?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000

Comment: Should table and figure be placed next to each, or one above the other? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

if figure and table are in the same float, they will be placed on the same page

```
\documentclass{article}           
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & b \\
a & b \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}

\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{image caption}
\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```