# Floating landscape environment

Tags: rotating, landscape

I have this construct in my document of a table that goes over the whole landscaped page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
         % lot of information, goes over whole page
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The only problem is the table goes exactly where I place it. The problem with using `\begin{sidewaystable}` from the `rotating` package is that it does not rotate the page when viewing it on PDF.

EDIT: Goal is to rotate the object and keep it as floating at the same time. (As pointed out by @Skillmon.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate single PDF page when viewing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/rotate-single-pdf-page-when-viewing)

Comment: Multiple solutions in the link above. I think the easiest one is to use the package `pdflscape` instead of `lscape`.

Comment: @Skillmon correct!

Comment: This is no duplicate of the question linked by @nox as this question not only asks to rotate the pdf  page but also to keep it as a float.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,fancyhdr,ifthen}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\value{page}}{\pageref{tt}}}
           {landscape \global\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90}}
           {portrait \global\pdfpageattr{}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

aaaa

    \begin{sidewaystable}
         \centering
       TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
         \caption{ttttt\label{tt}}

    \end{sidewaystable}


aaaaa

\pagebreak

aaaaa

aaaaa



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of an older question here: [How to wrap text around landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-wrap-text-around-landscape-page), although it's hard to say, since it's a bit strangely worded.

Anyway, the answer using the `afterpage` package did the trick for me.

```
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
         % lot of information, goes over whole page
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
}
```